# Getting specified data out of sqlite database with function?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a `ListView` with the names of each item inside the database but all I get back is the full table name. And if it is possible I want to use the same function to get other info like id later. If more information is needed ask me.

This is my code:

calling the function:

```
var categories = App.Database.GetCategoryByMenuID(1);
listView.ItemsSource = categories;
```

function:

```
public List<Categories> GetCategoryByMenuID(int menuID)
{
    return db.Table<Categories>().Where(x => x.Menu_ID == menuID).ToList();
}
```

table:

```
public class Categories
{
    public Categories()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Menu_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

thank you in advance,

Comment: `GetCategoryByMenuID`'s return trype is `List<Categories>` and how can it return `full table name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *var categories* is a List filled with multiple **Categories**. The ListView prints the name of the object in every row, which is: Categories.

You should make your own datatemplate that prints the attribute name of each "**Categories**".

Declare your own DataTemplate like this:

```
var datatemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
   var nameLabel = new Label();
   nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

   return new ViewCell { View = nameLabel };
}
```

Next up use your datatemplate to show the name of the categories. Instantiate your ListView like this:

```
var listView = new ListView
{
     ItemsSource = categories,
     ItemTemplate = datatemplate
}
```

Then your ListView will show the names.

Comment: after using you're code I get this error back: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item. .